# String Comparison set to boolean variable

Tags: c#

I assume this should be fine

```
bool prefMatch = false;

// Is the frequency the same?
prefMatch = string.Compare(user.Frequency, pref.Action.ToString()) == 0;
```

so if user.Frequency is "3" and pref.Action.ToString() is "3" then it should set the prefMatch to true right?  I'm getting false and I've definitely checked the 2 values in the watch tab in VS 2008 just to be sure they're the same

Comment: `String.Compare` isn't broken. :)

Comment: I actually had a different value being compared than I thought.  Works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `==`

```
prefMath = (user.Frequency == pref.Action.ToString());
```

Though `string.Compare` will also work. I suggest there is a problem elsewhere.

-- Edit

Also, just for completeness, there is no point assigning a variable to something, and then assigning it again directly after. It's slightly confusing to do so, so better to leave it unassigned, or assign it all in one spot. This way the compiler can help you if you have a case where it doesn't get assigned like you think. It is, obviously, acceptable to assign first if you wrap the second assignment in a `try/catch` though.

Answer (score 2):

In situations like these, it's sometimes tempting to point the finger of blame at third-party code, as you've done here. Sometimes, this is justified - but not here.  String.Compare is a central, extremely-well-tested piece of the .NET Framework.  It's not failing.  I guarantee it.

What I find helpful in these situations is to isolate the failure.  Write a small, self-contained test case that attempts to demonstrate the problem.  Write it with as few dependencies as possible.  Make it a stand-alone console application, if possible.  Post it here.  If we can take it, compile and run it, and reproduce the problem, we can help you.  I'd bet money, though, that in the course of creating this test case, you'll experience a head-slapping moment - "of course!" - and realize what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the string(s) contain unprintable characters ?
To check, I'd do something like :

```
byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(user.Frequency); 
byte[] b2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pref.Action.ToString());
```

then compare the contents of b1 and b2.